# Why my tests with localdb works fine in Azure DevOps?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, localdb

I use Azure DevOps for CI process of my .NET Core app.
Also I use integration tests based on localDb SQL database.
When I run my ci piplene I was surprised that all tests were passed.

```
{
      "UseInMemoryDatabase": false, // Application.IntegrationTests are not designed to work with InMemory database.
      "DeveloperPathSqlConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DeveloperPathTestDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;",
      "Key": {
        "Type": "Development"
      },
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Debug",
          "System": "Information",
          "Microsoft": "Information"
        }
      }
    }
```

Does Azure DevOps already contain the localdb?

Comment: Yes, if you use the Windows latest agent

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does Azure DevOps already contain the localdb?

The answer is yes.

The windows image contain the localdb. The [hosted windows agent](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md#workloads-components-and-extensions) comes with Visual Studio which includes LocalDB.

You could use following start command to verify:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'


- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'start mssqllocaldb'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'sqllocaldb start mssqllocaldb'
```

The test result:

[image]

Comment: The link you provided is for runner-images from github actions and the question was for Azure DevOps pipeline. 
I am a bit confuesd. Are those images the same for both providers or what?

Comment: They are the same.